# Fill DataGridView from SQL by using combobox

Tags: .net

I get an exception when i select an index of combobox.
the exception is `The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.`

Please help me how I can get data from sql in datagridview by selecting value of combobox"?

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=YASHPAL-VAIO;Initial Catalog=Akb;Integrated Security=True";
string sq = "SELECT * FROM studentinformation where registrationnumber= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sq, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter.Fill(ds);
connection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Debug sq.  Paste the command in SSMS and see if it runs.

Comment: What is the datasource of the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SelectedItem, which in this case will be a DataRowView (if you have bound the combo to a datasource), try using SelectedText?

If this is no good, get the selected combo item, cast as a DataRowView and then extract the value from there.